# Facebook login failed with android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

Stack Trace

05-30 16:50:36.015 7351-7351/com.example.android.facebooklogin     E/dalvikvm: Could not find class     'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
05-30 16:50:37.658 7351-7351/com.example.android.facebooklogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.android.facebooklogin, PID: 7351
                                                                             Log in attempt failed: LoginActivity could not be started
                                                                                 at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.startLogin(LoginManager.java:382)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginManager.java:262)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(LoginButton.java:693)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase$1.onClick(FacebookButtonBase.java:310)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4486)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18801)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:649)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

MainActivity.java

```
  package com.example.android.facebooklogin;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
    import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
    import com.facebook.FacebookException;
    import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
    import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
    import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView info;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        info.setText(
                                "User ID: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                        + "\n" + "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                        );
                    }
                    //
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        info.setText("Login attempt cancelled. ");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        info.setText("Login attempt failed. ");

                    }
                });
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.facebooklogin.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.facebooklogin">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <!--<activity android:name=".MainActivity">-->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"

            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

app id

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108618/could-not-find-class-android-graphics-drawable-rippledrawable

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108618/could-not-find-class-android-graphics-drawable-rippledrawable

Comment: @ND1010_ i couldn't find solution here.

Comment: what is your target device api version?

Comment: @darwin target device's android version is 4.4.2

Comment: which version of support library r u using?

Answer (score 0):

The [RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) was added in API 21, so it's not available on earlier SDKs.

You can move your drawable file to **res/drawable-v21** to ensure it doesn't crash on earlier releases.