# How can I run Google Fit Sample?

Tags: android, google-fit

I downloaded the sample at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit
and `Build a Project [StepCouter]` is ok.

But when I run on my device, an error occured:

```
02-27 16:37:18.620 26622-26622/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.stepcounter E/dalvikvm:
 Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
02-27 16:37:18.660 26622-26622/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.stepcounter E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.common.logger.LogView.setTextAppearance
     at com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.stepcounter.MainActivity.initializeLogging(MainActivity.java:161)
     at com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.stepcounter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5111)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5159)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:810)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:577)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the right permissions and scopes. You may follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization) on how to obtain authorization in Google Fit API.

> User consent is always required before your app can read or write fitness data. To obtain authorization:
>
> - [Register your Android app](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started) with a project in the Google Developers Console.
> - Specify a scope of access when connecting to the fitness service.
>
> In Google Fit, [scopes](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization#scopes) are strings that determine what kinds of [fitness data](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types) an app can access and the level of access to this data.

For the **`Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering`** error, you may refer with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108618/could-not-find-class-android-graphics-drawable-rippledrawable).